# Remove a previous element jquery

Tags: jquery, dom

I'd like to remove the `span` element from this HTML:

```
    <div class="selector" id="uniform-occupation_id">
        <span>Occupational Therapy Assistant</span>
        <select name="occupation_id" id="occupation_id" style="opacity: 0;">
            <option value="0">Select an Occupation</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Here is what I have thus far, although it seems to remove the select input element too!

```
    jQuery("#occupation_id").prev().empty();
```

Also, I need to check and see if a span exists before it.

Comment: You sure it's not just the `style="opacity: 0;"`? Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k8Tv3/.

Comment: That doesn't remove the element, it *empties* it.  To remove it, use `.remove()`

Comment: Are you saying that `$('#occupation_id').prev().empty()` removes everything in the div? Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Do you want to empty it or remove it? Title says one thing, your example says another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empty()` removes all child nodes.

Just use remove(), `jQuery("#occupation_id").prev().remove("span")`

Comment: That isn't the issue, it is because the opacity is 0.

Comment: `jQuery("#occupation_id").prev().remove()` is enough

Comment: And the select isn't a child of the span.

Comment: Why is the opacity an issue? The span either needs to be removed or emptied and the OP may be confused because he cannot see the select.

Comment: Because the select isn't visible on the page, but is still there.

Comment: resulting in the OP's confusion? @AndyG

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes, as j08691 spotted.

Answer (score 1):

To test if there is a previous element and that element is a span (your second question) you would do this -

```
if( $('select').prev('span').length ) {...
```